# How do I make sure that a string only contains the a–z and A–Z characters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm entering  the name of the user where I need to enter only a-z and A-Z only. I want to validate the name please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSCharacterSet *nonAlphabetChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];
if ([myString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonAlphabetChars].location == NSNotFound) {
    // myString is valid
    ...
} else {
    // myString contains at least one invalid character
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
NSCharacterSet *allowed = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
NSCharacterSet *forbidden = [allowed invertedSet];
NSRange range = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:forbidden];
BOOL isValid = (range.location == NSNotFound);
```

The `alphanumericCharacterSet` might not be exactly what you want, see `NSCharacterSet` for more options.